# How can I tell if a Microsoft Defender exclusion is working?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, windows-defender

Windows Security has the option of adding exclusions for files, folders, file types, and processes.  On a resource-constrained PC, I would like to add the programs that I use the most to the exclusion list.

My problem is that I do not seem to find any documentation on the format of exclusions (specifically, process exclusions).  Should it be in quotes, or without quotes?  The dialog does not give any validation, as to whether an entry is well-formed or not, and there doesn't seem to be any relevant documentation.  I can add a completely ill-formed path, and it does not give any feedback.

On my system, the exclusion dialog is found under Start > Settings > Update & Security > Windows Security > Virus & Threat Protection.  Then under Virus & threat protection settings, select Manage Settings.  Then under Exclusions, click Add or remove exclusions.

I am thinking that there may be a way with the SysInternals tools to see what Windows Defender is spending its resources on, but I don't really know.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-add-a-file-type-or-process-exclusion-to-windows-security-e524cbc2-3975-63c2-f9d1-7c2eb5331e53

Comment: If you can add a valid exclusion to Defender, it will work in my experience. Defender does not spend time on normal apps. Open Task Manager and see what your average CPU load is. I find it is less than 5% most of the time with normal operating loads.

Comment: Should an exclusion be in quotes or not?  Does it make a difference?

Comment: I have not had to use quotes to enter an exclusion.

Comment: You can use a third-party tool such as *Configure Defender*, https://github.com/AndyFul/ConfigureDefender, to show excluded items.